NX affect works for build but not for release
I'm having a nx monorepo for a design system and would like to publish packages to NPM only when they have changed.
Unfortunately this doesn't work for me as you can see here:
npx nx affected:build --base=origin/develop --exclude='storybook-host' --verbose
runs on 5 projects.
npx nx affected --target=release --base=origin/develop --verbose 
NX   No projects with target release for 0 projects were run
NX   Successfully ran target release for 0 projects
Why is that?
Project.json
{
  "name": "ds-components",
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "sourceRoot": "packages/ds-components/src",
  "projectType": "library",
  "tags": []
}

NX Workspace:
"release": {
    "projects": ["packages/*", "!storybook-host"],
    "projectsRelationship": "independent",
    "releaseTagPattern": "release/{projectName}/{version}",
    "changelog": {
      "projectChangelogs": true
    },
    "version": {
      "generatorOptions": {
        "packageRoot": "dist/packages/{projectName}",
        "currentVersionResolver": "git-tag",
        "projectChangelogs": true,
        "conventionalCommits": true,
        "specifierSource": "conventional-commits",
        "fallbackCurrentVersionResolver": "disk"
      }
    }
  },
  "targetDefaults": {
    "nx-release-publish": {
      "options": {
        "packageRoot": "dist/packages/{projectName}"
      }
    }
  },

